# Im having trouble with if statements

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, expression

I keep getting "expected initializer before 'if'" errors I was wondering if anyone can help me with that problem?I have this homework assignment that basically asks you to run a rock paper scissors game with 2 players.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x, y;

  std::cout << "Player 1 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "Player 2 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  std::cin >> y;
}
if ( x==1 ) and ( y==2 ) {
  std::cout << "Player 2 Wins! Paper Covers Rock!!\n";
}
else if ( x==1 ) and ( y==3 ) {
  std::cout << "Player 1 Wins! Rock Breaks Scissors!!\n";
}
else if ( x==1 ) and (x==1) {
  std::cout << "Tie with rock!\n";
}
else if ( x==2 ) and ( y==3 ) {
  std::cout <<  "Player 2 Wins! Scissors Cut Paper!!\n";
}
else if ( x==2 ) and ( y==1 ) {
  std::cout << "Player 1 wins! Paper Covers Rock!!\n";
}
else if ( x==2 ) and ( y==2 ) {
  std::cout << "Tie with Paper!\n"; 
}
else if ( x==3 ) and ( y==1 ) {
  std::cout << "Player 2 wins! Rock Breaks Scissors!!\n";
}
else if ( x==3 ) and ( y==2 ) {
  std::cout << "Player 1 wins! Scissors Cut Paper!!\n";
}
else if ( x==3 ) and ( y==3 ) {
  std::cout << "Tie with Scissors!";
}
else if (x>3){
 std::cout << "Invalid move!!\n";
}
else if (y>3){
  std::cout << "Invalid move!!\n";
}
return 0
}
```

Comment: you have closed the body of `main()` before the first `if`

Comment: Using `and` instead of `&&` in C++ is rather atypical. The former will lead to issues with operator precedence in more complicated expressions.

Comment: This is why its important to indent properly.

Comment: Oh ok where should I place the parentheses?

Comment: The first step is to remove the stray `}` after `std::cin >> y;`

Answer (score 2):

All the code must be in { } braces of the `main` function.

`if` code must have ( ) parentheses enveloping the whole expression. So it's `if ((x == 1) && (x == 2)) { ... }` instead of `if (x == 1) && (x == 2) { ... }`.

Also, use `&&` instead of `and` and `||` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the closing brace

```
int main()
{
  int x, y;

  std::cout << "Player 1 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "Player 2 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  std::cin >> y;
}  // <===
```

And expressions in if statements shall be enclosed in parentheses like

```
if ( ( x==1 ) and ( y==2 ) ) {
```

Comment: Better to keep `&&` in the answer isntead of syntactically wrong `and`

Comment: `if ( ( x==1 ) and ( y==2 ) ) {`

Comment: Ah! Excuse me. I never knew that we can use `and`.

Comment: @Wander3r In C++ this is an alternative token. In C you need to include the header <iso646.h> to use a macro as such a token.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x, y;

  cout << "Player 1 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Player 2 enter rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):";
  cin >> y;

if ( x == 1  &&  y == 2 ) {
  cout << "Player 2 Wins! Paper Covers Rock!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 1  &&  y == 3 ) {
  cout << "Player 1 Wins! Rock Breaks Scissors!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 1  && y == 1) {
  cout << "Tie with rock!\n";
}
else if ( x == 2  &&  y == 3 ) {
  cout <<  "Player 2 Wins! Scissors Cut Paper!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 2  &&  y == 1 ) {
  cout << "Player 1 wins! Paper Covers Rock!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 2  &&  y == 2 ) {
  cout << "Tie with Paper!\n"; 
}
else if ( x == 3  &&  y == 1 ) {
  cout << "Player 2 wins! Rock Breaks Scissors!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 3  &&  y == 2 ) {
  cout << "Player 1 wins! Scissors Cut Paper!!\n";
}
else if ( x == 3  &&  y == 3 ) {
  cout << "Tie with Scissors!";
}
else

  cout << "Invalid move!!\n";

return 0;
}
```

I had my professor help me but thanks for the help guys!!

Answer (score 0):

"Indentation error" Just place the closing brace of main function appropriately at the end.

```
int main() 
{

//all your logic here
. 
. 

} // closing brace
```

You got intialisation error because you have closed the main brace before if condition so it doesn't know with what value you have initialised x or y with.